# convert very big XML file to csv

Tags: xml, csv, converters

I have an XML file with 6Go ( a trace of my simulation) and I want to convert it into csv format?

is there a way to do this, I have 4GO of RAM for this application

this is a smaple of my xml file

```
<netstate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.sf.net/xsd/netstate_file.xsd">
    <timestep time="0.00">
        <edge id="-39539626">
            <lane id="-39539626_0">
                <vehicle id="flow0.0" pos="2.60" speed="0.00"/>
            </lane>
        </edge>
    </timestep>
    <timestep time="0.10">
        <edge id="-39539626">
            <lane id="-39539626_0">
                <vehicle id="flow0.0" pos="2.62" speed="0.25"/>
            </lane>
        </edge>
    </timestep>
```

what I really want is to get  `Vehicle ID an Lane ID` 
(and with precision I want Vehicle ID and the set of LaneID taken by this vehicle)

after I get the entry I want I will use it to get this output

```
Vehicule1:LaneID1,LaneID2,LaneID3,.....
Vehicule2:LaneID1,LaneID5,LaneID4,.....
Vehicle3:LaneID3,LaneID8,LaneID7,.....
...........
```

I am not using a specific language what I want is this output

for the moment I developped a function in java to read the csv file and then get the output I want

thank you in advance

Comment: Please give a meaningful sample of the XML and the required output for that sample. Also state what programming languages you know and are prepared to use.

Comment: Use SAX or Stax parser, You could parse large XML using those parser because the don't put entire XML in memory. and write CSV

Comment: thank you for the reply, I have updated my question,to present the output I want, could you please tell me more detail of using SAX is it some tool or it is a programming class?